# ASTParser: insert IfStatement before ExpressionStatement

Tags: java, if-statement, expression, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to find out how to insert an IfStatement before a singular ExpressionStatement.

For example, I have one `ExpressionStatement` node:

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

And after `visit(ExpressionStatement node)`, the node will be:

```
if ( 1 < 2)
   System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

I use ASTParser in Java to do this.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What problem?  You've given us no details about what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry @IraBaxter for my poor English, I have just edited. I just do not know how to do this.

Comment: Do you insist on using "ASTParser", or is any technical solution that is clear a useful answer to you?

Comment: I would guess OP's problem is the mechanics of making new nodes and splicing them in to the tree is non-obvious (and he claims non-documented).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what type of AST parser this is, but from your vague description I guess that you're trying to wrap a `if` around your expression statement.

Note that the code you provided is not an expression but a statement, in more detail an expression statement. Also, though the `if` is "before" the statement in the code, it's its parent in the AST, because it's exactly the same as if you'd wrap curly braces around the expression statement.

To wrap an `if` around the statement, you have to:

- get the parent of your *statement node*
- remove the *statement node* from its parent
- create a new *if node*
- give the *if node* it's *condition*
- set the *statement node* as the statement of the *if node*
- add the *if node* in the same place where the *expression node* was

So before manipulation the AST was:

```
// Code:
System.out.println("Hello World!");

// AST:
<Some node>
    ExpressionStatement                    // expression + ';'
        Expression                         // System.out...
            ...
```

After the manipulation it's:

```
// Code:
if(someCondition) System.out.println("Hello World!");

// AST:
<Some node>
    IfStatement                            // if(condition) statement
        Expression (Condition)             // someCondition
        ExpressionStatement (Statement)    // expression + ';'
            Expression                     // System.out...
                ...
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to use `visit(Statement node)`, @maxdev? It does not work at all.
But for `visit(ExpressionStatement node)`, it recognizes the node `System.out.println("Hello World!");`

Comment: furthermore, I like your idea but how can I solve it with your idea? Is there any tutorials? It seems that JDT does not have enough clear documentations or tutorials for ASTParser

Comment: @suti What exactly is your problem? Finding `<Some node>`? Creating new nodes?

Comment: @maxdev Your example code contains an additionally `Block` node (the curly braces)! with [ASTRewrite](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/rewrite/ASTRewrite.html) you don't need to get the parent node of the expression. (But you will need a dummy node)

Comment: suti, I tried to explain it implementation-independent, what is the exact problem? @Absurd-Mind it doesn't matter if there are curly braces, it's a statement in any way.

Comment: @maxdev Yes this is right, but your code does not represents the AST. The code would be: `if (someCondition) System.out.println("Hello World!");`. It's not very important was just pointing out.

Comment: Aah @Absurd-Mind I see what you mean, it's important, I fixed it :)